# how to disable big letter while clicking key of iphone keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

I am doing a customized keyboard. I disable default keys on keyboard from not showing already, but not yet disable the big letter while go around it. As you can see below, how can we disable this default big letter?

[image: big letter]

This is the code that I disable default letter from not showing.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSCharacterSet *disabledLetters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "] invertedSet];
NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:disabledLetters];
return (location.location == NSNotFound);}
```

However, I not yet disable the behavior of each key(disable actions when we click on them and make them not bigger). how can I do that ?

Comment: You'll have to make your own keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use default keyboard when showing and then I will draw my own buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it's part of UIKit and you're not allowed to interfere with it.

You'd better design a full replacement keyboard and use it as your textfield’s `inputView`. Beware that not everyone uses QWERTY, though (here in France I use AZERTY layout).

Comment: I just want to use it and customize. That is what my company wants !

Comment: Well this app would be rejected from the App Store for this behaviour. Your company will need to change its requirements.

Comment: My company wants me to work 180 hours per week on four projects at the same time. You can't always get what you want.